# View shrinks on adding ScrollView in react-native

Tags: view, react-native, scrollview

I have made whole UI, but when I am adding a SrollView on the parent View , the view is shrinking , what should I do ?

Comment: Can you share code snippet ? may be you are using flex and thats why the views shrinks, instead try fix height style.

Comment: @Rajesh
yes , I am using flex. 
If I use fixed heights, then screen resolution of different devices will cause problems.

Comment: how ? Fixed height would not cause any issues. If you think u have to use flex according to width , then in fixed height layouts you can use flex.  share codebase..